# Azure Devops Release > Powershell task > Building a scheduled task

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, scheduled-tasks, azure-keyvault

I'm trying to build a Powershell function that will create a Windows Scheduled Task on my onPrem server as part of my Azure release pipeline, which will need to run with the "Run whether user is logged on or not", so I am passing it an AD Service account UserID & Password.

This works totally fine if I use a plain text password from a variable, but I would like to import the password from my Azure KeyVault. I'll call it "PasswordFromKeyVault".

I have added a new Variable Group, linked to the Keyvault and it retrieves the value correctly.

Here is the Powershell script I am using in this step:

```
$TaskName = "HelloNewTaskWorld"
$Trigger= New-ScheduledTaskTrigger -At 10:02am -Daily

$Action= New-ScheduledTaskAction -Execute "PowerShell.exe" -Argument "C:\PowershellScripts\Somescript.ps1"

$principal = New-ScheduledTaskPrincipal -UserId $(PlainTextUserIdVariable) -LogonType ServiceAccount
$description = "Testing AzureDevOps ability to deploy a fully configured scheduled task"

#As expected, outputs xxx to the console
Write-Host $(PasswordFromKeyVault)


Register-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName -Description $description -Trigger $Trigger -Action $Action -Principal $principal –Force
Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName -User $principal.UserID -Password $(PasswordFromKeyVault)
```

But when it runs, I receive the error message "The user name or password is incorrect":

```
2022-04-11T16:18:23.0724016Z Set-ScheduledTask : The user name or password is incorrect.
2022-04-11T16:18:23.0724884Z At C:\vstsagent\XW14Agent1\_work\_temp\90f67b9e-e6f7-4f71-9be9-fe24498f535e.ps1:16 char:1
2022-04-11T16:18:23.0725477Z + Set-ScheduledTask -TaskName $TaskName -User $principal.UserID -Passwo ...
2022-04-11T16:18:23.0726111Z + ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2022-04-11T16:18:23.0726638Z     + CategoryInfo          : AuthenticationError: (PS_ScheduledTask:Root/Microsoft/...S_ScheduledTask) [Set-Scheduled 
2022-04-11T16:18:23.0727110Z    Task], CimException
2022-04-11T16:18:23.0727497Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : HRESULT 0x8007052e,Set-ScheduledTask
```

I assume this is because the Azure Keyvault value is encrypted, and cannot be decrypted (which is exactly what I want), but does anyone know how I can create a credential using an already encrypted password?

Comment: I think you have to send the password as secure string. ```$Password = "ABCDEF@1234"
$passwordFromKeyVault = ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText $Password -Force ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Edit - 17/04/2022

---

The error:   `The user name or password is incorrect`
,can be  resolved by checking and  placing the password retrieved in double quotes to get the actual vaule .
i.e; like

```
"$(PasswordFromKeyVault)"
```

---

### 14/04/2022

1. Please make sure to set an  access policy or policies in Azure Key
   Vault for the Azure DevOps project application principal /service
   account with `List/Get` permissions on Secrets and make sure the
   name of the KeyVault and azureSubscription are both correct.
   You can refer to this [blog](https://zimmergren.net/using-azure-key-vault-secrets-from-azure-devops-pipeline/).
2. Configure the [Environment Variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_environment_variables?view=powershell-7.2) , see
   [stack overflow Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60336058/how-to-inject-an-azure-key-vault-password-into-a-mysql-script-during-pipeline-ru)

   Secret variables are usually encrypted .So to pass a secret to a
   script, we can make use of the those Environment section of the
   scripting task’s input variables. If environment variables in
   pipeline are something like:

   > Name :password  | value :$(mypassword)

   Now, try with calling your variable with `$env: password` in your
   script.

***Set-up PS Credentials***

```
$Username = "$env:USERDOMAIN\local-admin"
```

> **NOTE:** **Key Vault name and Secret name** should be retrieved via **“normal”**
> variables using inherited environment variable.
> for example.
>
> ```
> $Secret = (Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "myKeyVaultName" -Name "kvTestSecret").SecretValueText
>  Write-Host  "PowerShell Get-AzKeyVaultSecret: $Secret"
> ```
>
> References:
>
> - [powershell - Not able to print the Azure-Keyvault secret in the    release pipeline - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59250555/not-able-to-print-the-azure-keyvault-secret-in-the-release-pipeline)
> - [Managing Azure Key Vault access and secrets from DevOps pipeline    (techgenix.com)](https://techgenix.com/azure-key-vault-access-devops/)

```
[string]$AdminPassword = Get-AzKeyVaultSecret -VaultName "***" -Name "***" -AsPlainText
//or$ AdminPassword=$env: password
[securestring]$SecureAdminPassword = $AdminPassword | convertto-securestring -AsPlainText -Force
//or $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "PasswordHere" -AsPlainText -Force

$cred = new-object -typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Username, $SecurAdminPassword
//or $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username,$SecurAdminPassword)

//Then you can Set-up Scheduled Task parameters
```

Check **[this](https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/sylt2l/comment/hxyfpfl/?utm_source=share&utm_medium=web2x&context=3)**.

**References:**

1. [Dynamicallly get KeyVault secret in Azure DevOps Powershell script -
   Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58607998/dynamicallly-get-keyvault-secret-in-azure-devops-powershell-script)
2. [Azure Key Vault task - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/azure-key-vault?view=azure-devops)
3. [about Quoting Rules - PowerShell | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2)